# iOS - Flutter audioplayers plugin error on xcode (Not found) on Release mode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator, release

When I test it on iOS Simulator on debug mode, it works fine but when I try to run on release mode on XCode it give me the following error:

Module 'audioplayers' not found

I use audioplayers 0.18.3

I remove the Pods and reinstall but not effect in release mode. Don't have problem with archive the app so is very strange. Need take screenshots of the app (in release mode, without debug banner) and I don't have a physical iOS device, so the only solution for me is take screenshots from iOS Simulator in release mode, but have this problem

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SETGK.jpg)

PD: I'm running the **.xcworkspace** file.

PD2: I'm running flutter build ios and open xcode (**.xcworkspace** file), and run 'clean build folder' but the error persist

PD3: Sorry my bad english

Thanks since now!